# Set Origin header in Chrome extension for Get request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have added a additional layer of security over my REST API endpoint by verifying the Origin header of the incoming request. If the header contains my extension url i.e. chrome-extension://<my_extension_unique_id> then only proceed ahead with the request.

If I add my api url or <all_url> in host_permission section of extension's manifest it doesn't add Origin header.

How can I add Origin header to the GET request with <all_url> host permission.

I have already tried chrome.declarativeNetRequest api and was successfully able to add origin header.
Is there any other way to do this apart from manipulating the request.